# Stack Apps FAQ is missing a section

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, stackapps, site-faq

[image: the phrase "the above section" directly under the page header]

There is no "above section" presented. Not sure if this is a typo (`s/above/below`), some optional text that shouldn't be getting displayed or an indication that a summary section is missing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was actually a missing style, that section should be hidden unless you come in with a url hash.

Added the style, and the fix will go out with the next build.